# jQuery .slider is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a jQuery slider onto my webpage but it is throwing me the error:

```
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function`
```

This is my link list in the :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/search.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCtf7Q1QeO9cQfwsBo7FQ-g3en_zJbk8Iw&callback=initMap" async defer>
</script>
```

And here is the JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( function() {
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  values: [ 100, 300 ],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).html( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
$( "#amount1" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
$( "#amount2" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
  }
});
$( "#amount" ).html( "£" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
 " - £" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
</script>
```

I think the problem might be something to do with this template I am using which is used on the page. In the template there is another jQuery.js file which I believe to be the same version used on this page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/function.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can't load `jquery.min.js` and `jquery.js` even if it is the same version. Get rid of one.

Comment: So try removing the jquery from the template, the min version and the unminified version will clash.

Comment: I removed the jquery.js from the template and added the jquery.min.js to it but it is still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error $(...). The term "slider" does not refer to a function. I tried every remedy I could think of. However, jquery and jquery-ui sequencing fixed the problem. I was using jquery-ui instead of jquery.

In the proper order